# How to use a query result in a new query

Tags: xml, xslt

The XML data I have to process has 2 similar nodes, one is the active and one is the backup.
the active node is found like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ATTRIBUTE">
  <xsl:if test="@NAME='ActiveConfig'">
    <xsl:variable name="activeAttendant" select="VALUE"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$activeAttendant"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I have a second query that can list all information from the configuration.

How can I combine the two so that the 2nd query uses the value found in the above outlined query and pulls the information from the active configuration and not the backup?

I tried to use:

```
<xsl:call-template name="DNIS">  
<xsl:with-param name="$activeAttendant"/>
```

but it fails within the `xsl:if` and `xsl:for-each`

I use notepad++ and MS Visual Studio to develop and the end result needs to run inside IE 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are specifying the *value* in the *name* attribute of the xsl:with-param.**

[xsl:with-param](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-with-param) has `@name` and `@select` atttributes. `$activeAttendant` should be in the `@select` attribute and you should have a @name attribute where you specify the param name.

It should be something like this:

```
<xsl:with-param name="my-param-name" select="$activeAttendant"/>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow you Mads. The name I specify here is
 
    <xsl:variable name="activeAttendant" select="VALUE"/>

So what should I use then here as name because that to me is activeAttendant?

Comment: You are attempting to apply a parameter to the DNIS template. What is the name of the parameter? It would be helpful if you posted the DNIS template, in order to see what you are trying to invoke .

Comment: I've put the files on the following dropbox link: <https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p0nrfc1ba0ao98m/LpIbN7XWh3>. The DNIS are phone numbers that are stored and match with IVR nodes.